# After Collision My Score is being added more then 1 per each collision

Tags: javascript

When my player collides with the gem I would like the score to go up 1 each time this happens. Yet, each time it happens my score increases by more then 1. Please help.

I've tried using a boolean but then it doesn't work since 1 is added to my score only ONCE.

```
var score = 0;
gemG.prototype.update = function(){
    if ((this.x > player.x - 75 && this.x < player.x + 75) && (this.y > player.y - 75 && this.y < player.y + 75)) {
        setTimeout(()=>{
            document.getElementById("scoreNum").innerHTML = score += 1;

            this.y= Math.floor(Math.random() * 150) + 50;
            this.x=Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)+100
            player.y = 400;
            player.x = 200;
        },200);
    }
};
```

UPDATE: Works now problem was the set timeout. Once I got rid of it it worked.

Comment: When should the score be increased? Can you describe your overall game?

Comment: The score should be increased for each collision that occurs. I would like it to increase by 1 for each collision. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: My overall game is when the player contacts with the gem, the score should be increased by 1 for each collision that occurs and the gem will reposition. Only problem is that the score increasing isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current logic is *on every update, if the player collides, increase the score*. Instead you want your logic to be *on every update, if the player collides and did not collide before, increase the score*. For that, you need to store the previous state somewhere:

```
  let didCollide = false;
```

Then on every check:

```
  let collides = 
     this.x > player.x - 75 && this.x < player.x + 75 && 
     this.y > player.y - 75 && this.y < player.y + 75;

  if(collides && !didCollide) {
    score += 1;
  }

  didCollide = collides;
```

Comment: Ok, well I found out the problem. It was the set timeout and I got rid of it and it started working